# Typedef not appearing in template when using gulp-jsdoc-to-markdown

Tags: node.js, gulp, jsdoc, jsdoc2md

I am trying to create automatically generated documentation for our node.js API. I am using jsDoc style comments and gulp to run the generation. I am using the plugin [jsdoc2md](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown) and this [gulp plugin](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/gulp-jsdoc-to-markdown) to create markdown style documentation.

I am running into an issue of my typedefs not showing up in the generated documentation when i try to use a template. They show up when i do not use a template

Here is gulp task

```
gulp.task("docs", function() {
    return gulp.src(["./documentation/typedefs.js", "./routes/**/*.js"])
        .pipe(concat("README.md"))
        .pipe(gulpJsdoc2md({ template: fs.readFileSync('./README.hbs', 'utf8') }))
        .on("error", function(err) {
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.red("jsdoc2md failed"), err.message);
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./api"));
});
```

Here is my template

```
# My Super Cool API
This is where stuff happens

# Search API
{{#module name="search-api"}}
{{>body~}}
{{>member-index~}}
{{>separator~}}
{{>members~}}
{{/module}}
```

The output of this is a markdown with the appropriate functions and modules, but lacking the typedefs. So my question is:

**How can I get my typdefs to render in the template?**

The documentation doesn't have much. Any ideas?

Comment: typedefs render fine in jsdoc2md.. please post your souce code so we can check you have defined the typedefs correctly.. do the docs render correctly in jsdoc?

Comment: I unfortunately no longer have the source code, as I have moved on to a different solution. And yes, the docs were rendering correctly when I wasn't using the template. The issue only came up when i was using the template.